# Getting Error on AJAX Submit of Angular Form

Tags: angularjs, ajax, forms

Getting the below error:

```
 OPTIONS http://localhost:4444/Examples/Form net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The Angular JS code used:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
var enrolledUser = {};
$scope.enrolledUser = enrolledUser;
console.log("Func");
$scope.sendPost = function(){
    console.log("Func Called");
    $http.post('http://localhost:4444/Examples/Form',enrolledUser);
};
}]);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
 <form name="enrollform" class="css-form" novalidate >
    <label for="empNo">Employee Number* :</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="enrolledUser.empNo" name="empNo" ng-required/> 
    <span ng-show="enrollform.empNo.$error.required">Employee Number is mandatory!!</span> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn_success" ng-click="sendPost()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> Detailed Error received on console:
>
> angular.js:12759 OPTIONS http://localhost:4444/Examples/Form
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> angular.js:14700 Possibly unhandled
>   rejection:{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":null],
>   "jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:4444/Examples/Form","data":{"empNo":"1","track":"1","designation":"SE","category":"UI","subCategory":"AngularJS"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain,
>   */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}

Comment: Does your server allow OPTIONS requests?

Comment: Is your angular code running on same server as the backend or it's under nodejs or similar, with different port?

Comment: I am new to angular, I am using eclipse IDE and Tomcat server for the project.

Comment: Then they will be running on the same Server and coming to server allow OPTIONS requests. How to check this? and I was able to navigate to servlet and was able to see the JSON sent on Browsers' Network too.