# How to retrieve JSON data from Angular request to access another domain's resources?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http, access-control

I have a strange problem that I have been working on for a couple of days.
The problem is related to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing(CORS), I am making an Angular `GET` request and able to see in the developer tools of Firefox/Chrome that JSON response body is received, however JavaScript (or the browser, or the server) is refusing to hand me the response body.
Here is my request:

```js
$http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http"); //angular http object
 $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http"); 
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api.example.com/myPath',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
  
      alert("succeed: db "+JSON.stringify(response)); //this is not called
    

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      alert("failed: " + JSON.stringify(response));//this is called
    });
```

As mentioned in the comments the fail function is called not the success.
I can mention/post the Stack-overflow and other links that I have been to here, but there are like 50 of them, so here are some of them:

1. [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993510/angularjs-1-http-always-return-status-code-1-when-request-fails)
2. [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402156/getting-error-on-ajax-submit-of-angular-form?rq=1)
3. [SO 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573140/problems-with-get-call-to-rest-api)
4. [SO 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573140/problems-with-get-call-to-rest-api)
5. [SO 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065471/bad-request-error-in-angularjs)
6. [Reddit 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/7ecfsm/http_failing_to_get_a_response/)
7. [SO 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292481/getting-the-response-as-datanull-status-1-when-calling-web-api-from-angula/43308445)
8. [GitHub 1](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1398)

Headers I have tried (beside what shown in the code):

```
"headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }


"headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }

"headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }


"headers": {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }


"headers": {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }
```

Tried all the above, some of them will not receive JSON response, instead the Send `OPTIONS` request and stop.

This is what Firefox output looks like:

[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9DRv.jpg)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wcY1.jpg)

And here is the Alert function output :

```
failed: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"api.example.com/myPath","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}
```

Other things I tried:
Installing Plugin for Chrome called CORS : [Was not effective at all, no difference](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

**Note** The Endpoints server is not NodeJS, It is Java, Most of the answers I have come across online suggest adding these **headers at the server**, but my colleagues **insist** that this problem can be solved using front-end Angular (Especially after they saw that the correct response body Json information is actually coming from the server as shown in the pictures attached)

Comment: if u can see it in the browser then it means the backend is good and there is not a cors prob

Comment: Which version of angularjs are u using?

Comment: not sure which version I am using because I installed it using NPM, I am using this package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular and then include the file path in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there is no Fix from front-end only, the browser is handing me back the JSON response data only after the Java endpoint added response headers, in NodeJS I had it working fine before with the following addition:

```
 request(options, function(err, response, body) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.json(response);
  })
```

I am not sure how that is done in Java but that's basically what they did, just added these things to Java Web-service.
It is like the Java server (although sending JSON response to the browser)was telling the browser ("Do not hand him the data because I do not have such instructions on my end"). it is a bit comical I guess but that is what it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angularjs version >= 1.4 , do it like this (notice the catch)

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'api.example.com/myPath',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  alert("succeed: db "+JSON.stringify(response)); //this is not called

}).catch(function(response) {
  alert("failed: " + JSON.stringify(response));//this is called
});
```

Comment: I already tried that, did not make a difference, not sure which version I am using because I installed it using NPM, I am using this package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular and then include the file path in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$http.get('api.example.com/myPath').then(
  function(res){ 
    alert('success')
    },
   function(err){
     alert(err)
  })
```

Comment: alert box outputs the error (added JSON.stringify(err) )   : {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"api.example.com/myPath'","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}